# How to show payment icon of braintree payments in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, braintree-sandbox

I am calling

> func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String){}

the method with my token and put test credit card number(4111 1111 1111 1111) in my PaymentSelectController but I want to show the credit card icon as well as credit card number to next OrderConfirmationController.

Something like this:

[image]

What is the best/effective idea for this?

Comment: How are you showing it in your UI? Can you post an image? Are you displaying it in a UILabel or UITextfield?

Comment: Here is my design snapshot

https://pasteboard.co/HorRtQD.png

Comment: Are you designing your own UI or is it braintree's UI?

Comment: UI provided by client

Comment: Then I am afraid you won't be able to customize it. How is it provided? A static framework or bunch of classes to add? Can you access the UI elements and update them?

Comment: Can I use result.paymentIcon in a view/imageview?

Comment: According to the documentation, if you are using builtin drop-in controller then the UI is provided by the SDK.